# Only show certain nested fields in aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the aggregate query:

```
db.laureates.aggregate([
{ $match : { "nobelPrizes.affiliations.name.en" : "CERN" }},
{ $project : { _id: 0, "nobelPrizes.affiliations.country.en" : 1 }},
{ $limit : 1}]).pretty()
```

which results in this:

```
{
        "nobelPrizes" : [
                {
                        "affiliations" : [
                                {
                                        "country" : {
                                                "en" : "Switzerland"
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

The resulting value of the query is correct (Switzerland), but I am trying to only print certain fields in the result, namely country. It should look like this:

```
{ "country" : "Switzerland" }
```

How do I exclude the fields beside the "country" field? I'm aware that the projection part of the aggregate pipeline can exclude fields parallel to the one being targeted, but how can this be done for nested fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$unwind` to flat the array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$nobelPrizes"},
  { "$unwind": "$nobelPrizes.affiliations"},
  { $match: { "nobelPrizes.affiliations.country.en": "Switzerland"}},
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "country": "$nobelPrizes.affiliations.country.en"
    }
  },
  { $limit: 1 }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lV2_ucUVP-8)**